# Why does centrifugal force cause gravity?

Tags: artificial-gravity, humans

I have read several space books on processing resources in space.  They talk about using distillation by rotating a section.  WOuldn’t the centrifugal force cause the mixture to separate by its self?  Also, if we spin a space station, won’t everyone living in it get nausea?

Comment: To prevent nausea, a larger diameter of the rotating station may be helpful. The difference between the centrifugal forces at the head and feet of the astronaut should be small.

Comment: The answer to your title question was given by Albert Einstein who said that gravity and acceleration are equivalent

Comment: This is really three distinct questions and should probably bet split up that way.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question here.

Comment: though this is a Q&A site, please keep in mind that the questions are also supposed to be useful for other readers.  That means separating out questions so that other people could find them using the search function, and doing at least a little research before asking them.

Comment: Your title does not match your post's content.

Comment: once your question has been answered, please don't edit it to invalidate existing answers.  This is why we close questions that aren't clear, to try to prevent the questions and answers coming disconnected.  The goal is to have answers available for anyone who comes looking.

Comment: Your proposed edit wasn't clear anyway. Before posting it as a separate question, please take some time to clearly state the problem, then do some research on your own first.

Answer (score 2):

Distillation is separation by phase partitioning. There are two phases (liquid and vapor) with different concentrations due to differences in vapor pressure. The two phases are kept separate by their difference in density. This can be done using gravitational acceleration or, in space, by centripetal acceleration.

Stills often use heat to speed up the separation, but this is not necessary as long as there is a difference in concentration between the constituents in liquid vs, gaseous phases. Under vacuum, distillation can be done below room temperature.

Vapor is removed (and then condensed) from the vapor phase, which has a higher concentration of the substance of interest than the liquid phase. This can be done as a continuous or batch process.

The phase partitioning can be done in the absence of gravity (e.g.: membrane distillation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_distillation), but it would be challenging to harvest the vapor phase.

Solutions cannot be separated efficiently by centrifugation, although ultracentrifuges can produce a concentration gradient in a solution. But ultracentrifuges operate at up to 100,000 gravities. Moonshine stills operate just fine at 1 gravity, as described to me    /;0)

Answer (score 2):

Some mixtures will separate gradually under normal earth gravity, but using a centrifuge to put it under hundreds of Gs will vastly speed up the process, or pull apart mixtures that have too much electrical attraction to separate normally. For example, blood will separate out into various components when centrifuged.

But many mixtures don't separate under any reasonable amount of acceleration (whether it's from gravity or a centrifuge). You can't use a medical centrifuge to distil alcohol, for example -- the electrical attraction between the water and ethanol is too strong to be overcome by the relatively small difference in density. And in some cases, like salt water, the salt completely breaks down into ions in the water and can't be separated by any amount of force, because there aren't just little salt molecules floating around in the water; they've dissolved at a molecular level.

Distillation gets around that by using heat to overcome that attraction. You heat the mixed fluids to a point where one of them evaporates (or boils) more than the other one, and then you capture the steam so you can condense it back into a more concentrated form. Repeat several times to improve the concentration.

But in space, there's a problem: Steam doesn't rise. Even though steam is less dense than water, in space, a bubble of steam will form directly around the heater, but nothing forces it to move one way while the water goes the other way. This can be resolved with even a relatively slow rotation; that should give it enough acceleration to separate the dense water from the less-dense steam, and now you can tap off the steam into a condensation tube (where you probably also want gravity to make the condensate collect in a container).